# Line network integration analysis in QGIS

Tags: qgis, network-analysis, qgis-network-analysis

I want to analyse how integrated a line (e.g. road, stream) is within a network.
I want to perform the "integration" type of analysis identified by Javadi (not the connectivity or choice analysis) i.e. the integration analysis performed by Depthmap (I've been unable to get the analysis to work in Depthmap due to presumably data issues).

I think I just need a plugin, but I don't know which one does this analysis.

Figure illustrating the difference between connectivity, integration and choice for a sample network. Taken from: Javadi, A., et al. (2017) “Hippocampal and prefrontal processing of network topology to simulate the future”. Nature Communications.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I guess the plugin you need is Space Syntax toolkit. It is a QGIS plug-in for spatial network and statistical analysis. It provides a front-end for the depthmapX software within  QGIS.

Comment: Hi Damini, unfortunately it didn't seem to have the algorithm required for the analysis. Thanks anyway!

Comment: can you please elaborate on this more?

Comment: https://www.ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/gess/cognitive-science-dam/images/COG%20Teaching/Tutorial/15MAY%20Depthmap%20network%20analysis%20tutorial.pdf hope this helps though it isnt in QGIS but still it might help you in getting your desired results.

Comment: http://otp.spacesyntax.net/software-and-manuals/space-syntax-toolkit-2/getting-started/ in QGIS

Comment: Hi Damini, looks like the Space Syntax toolkit might have what I need after all, I'll confirm once I've looked into it

Comment: Sure! Lemme know :)

Comment: Can you upvote my answer then :) ?

Comment: Upvoted, but I don't have enough reputation to affect the public view, sorry